# How to get rid all strange characters that can't get into mysql from a string in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, character, utf8mb4

I have a problem with strange character.

In mysql this character  cause error `Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x80'`

Samples of these characters are from https://foursquare.com/v/shabushi-%E0%B8%8A%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%8A/4b72452cf964a5203c762de3

Say I want to analyze data from the web and found some strange character

how to remove this character  ??

The occurance is rare.

In fact, how to know all characters that may be problematic for mysql and remove that? I am not saying escapeable characers. I am saying characters that are neither numeric, alphabeth, or chinese scripts, or punctuation. Characters that's totally bizarre.

How do I get rid of that from a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of MySQL can't deal with characters outside the BMP; [upgrade your MySQL to at least 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-upgrading.html) and [set the column to use the `utf8mb4` charset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).

Comment: what is bmp? I am just curious.

Comment: The [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), where all Unicode codepoints fit in 16 bits, and all UTF-8 encodings use 3 or fewer bytes.

Comment: so you mean all those are characters outside BMP?

Comment: Not all, but certainly some of them. That's why you get a 4-byte "Incorrect string value".